Extending the ForgeRock AM AbstractDecisionNode
I have a set of code that is using the AbstractDecisionNode from ForgeRock AM (https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/7.3/_attachments/apidocs/org/forgerock/openam/auth/node/api/AbstractDecisionNode.html) but need to add an additional outcome of 'redirect'.  Use case being, this is part of a collector node and if the user clicks a different button, I need to pass an additional outcome to this node for a redirect / logoff type of decision.  Has anyone extended this node to add an additional outcome / examples you may be able to provide?
Thanks
Nick

As the Node‘s definition is to have exactly 2 outcomes (true and false), I would recommend you to derive from the Node interface instead. There you‘d be able to set more outcomes.
